# CoffeeScript source maps for nodeJS development

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, source-maps

Now that CoffeeScript supports the new Source Map hotness, I was wondering if I can also use the source maps not just in my browser, but on the command line while developing my nodeJS apps.

I want the JS compiler to give me more useful error traces where the lines actually match with my coffeescript files instead of compiled JS files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now with CoffeeScript 1.6.2 it just "works" if you run your app with the `coffee` command :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for .coffee files that are included with `require` - I'm seeing stuff like `main.coffee:12:1, <js>:20` but then `imported.coffee:185:3` and the `imported.coffee` only has 130 lines of coffeescript.

Comment: Being exasperated with the current solutions, I've made this:
https://npmjs.org/package/coffee-script-mapped

Let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 18):

The [source-map-support](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support) module does this, just install the module and put this at the top of your code:

```
require('source-map-support').install()
```

Comment: this doesnt appear to work with coffee-script 1.6.3 and node v0.10.23. coffee-script-mapped works great though. Perhaps its because I'm running my code without compiling it first? IE, I do

    require('coffee-script');  
    require('source-map-support').install();  

and then all required files are coffee files.

Comment: @rbrc [This pull request of mine](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support/pull/75) might address your issue with `source-map-support`.

Answer (score 3):

Until coffee-script gets some better support for require(), try this:
https://npmjs.org/package/coffee-script-mapped

Comment: if you're running node, how would you go about using this?

Comment: this answer is a bit out of date now, from my recollection coffee-script it self supports require already.